# UITextView and UILabel do not display full text if 9 or more lines?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying various methods, functions, extensions : Here is my issue.

I get a text response from the backend API, its a single line of text, but will have HTML tags for line breaks. So some long strings are supposed to look like bullet points or multiple paragraphs. Also I will have to parse out URL links, email and phone numbers, so I want to use a UITextView

My Problem : the textView almost never displays more than a few lines and I have to scroll up and down many times to get the full text to load. and sometimes the rounded corners are not rounded. I need 3 rounded corners specifically.

Normally this is easy. But this is seriously stumping me.

I have tried setting scrolling to false. I have setup my constraints too many times to count.

I don't want to beg but I am happy to mail some KitKats to whomever can help!

Here is my cellForRowAt and my cell classes

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    let sending = message.from?.id == BotClient.shared.currentUser.id
    switch sending {   
    case true:
    // User Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
        cell.transform = tableView.transform
        cell.messageLabel.text = message.text
        return cell   
    case false:
        // Bot Cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BotCell", for: indexPath) as! BotCell
            cell.testLabel.text = message.text
            cell.testLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.transform = tableView.transform
            return cell
        }
    }
}

// Bot Cell Class
class ReadMoreCell : UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: EdgeInsetLabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let bounds: CGRect = testLabel.bounds
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 15.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                   maskLayer.frame = bounds
                    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    testLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer
    testLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

}

// User Cell Class
class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
static let reuseId = "UserCell"
@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: EdgeInsetLabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
            let bounds: CGRect = messageLabel.bounds
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    messageLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer
    messageLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    messageLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
// Do I put UI Configurations like border colors, and round corner stuff here ??
}
```

}

image : [the GRAY cell is supposed to take up the full length of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzZ3W.png)

Comment: Does setting the vertical content compression resistance priority to 1000 with no scrolling help?

Comment: Are you calculating your cell/row height correctly with the message text?

Comment: I just tried resistance priority to 1000 and no scrolling. Still the textView is cut off.  I have my constraints as : bottom of UITextView to bottom of cell, Top of UITextView to top of cell. Left margin of 16 and right margin of 175.

Comment: Do I use heightForRowAt ? I tried automaticDimension there and nothing.

Comment: Im really struggling on this. =(

Comment: You have to calculate cell height based on the message text as it would be different for different messages right? Yo are using automatic dimensions for your label/texView inside the cell but not for the cell itself, right?

Comment: I think so? I tried tableView.automaticDimensions in ViewDidLoad, and I also tried automaticDimensions in heightForRow, but that's it. I also tried setting the estimated height over 100. I am missing something basic